# Disable Yoast SEO on custom post type for specific user role

Tags: wordpress, seo, meta-boxes, yoast

I've made a custom post type, where I want different users to only edit their posts. I've made some restrictions regarding their capabilities on the site and the posts - I don't want them to be able to edit anything other than a few textinputs and such.

For some reason I can't find a way to disable the Yoast SEO metabox on the posts - I've checked Yoast's own doc, but I haven't been able find anything regarding this besides using a plugin called User Role Editor, which doesn't work the way I need.

I've tried the snippet from [this place](https://www.mootpoint.org/blog/disable-yoast-wordpress-seo-for-certain-roles/), but it doesn't seem to work either.

TL;DR: Remove Yoast SEO on custom post type for a specific user.

Comment: Ask question when you stuck in code which will try to give answers to guide you or trying new possibilities in life of coding. So first do some code and then come back here if you stuck any where. 

Please read - How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ADMIN MENU EDITOR PRO](https://adminmenueditor.com/) Plugin

With this plugin, you can choose every parts you want to display by user role in the admin.

This si the simple method.